# Create login system with different users to postgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql-9.1

I'm a newcomer to postgreSQL, I'm using version 9.1
I want to create a login system with different users with different rights.

What I have in mind....

There is a simple user, lets call him "visitor". He can only "select" from the users table.
When someone gives the login and password to sign in, php grabs the login and password and connects to the db as "visitor". If matching pair found (log/pass given-log/pass in table are the same), then lets start the session and so on, like

```
session_start();
        $_SESSION['authenticated']=true;
            while ($arr=pg_fetch_array($r)) {
```

lets save user's id

```
$_SESSION['c_id']=$arr['c_id'];
```

and lets save user's "role". Role is a simple int, found in the users table. It defines the rights of each user. If it is 1 , user can update/insert/delete a table. If it is 2 user can update/insert/delete two tables and if it is 3 user can update/insert/delete two tables and also add new users, in "levels" 1 and 2 (superuser).

This simply means that each user has different menous, so lets use a simle "if" to guide them to different menous.

```
$_SESSION['role']=$arr['role'];

if ($_SESSION['role']==1){header('Location:menouOne.php');} 
elseif ($_SESSION['role']==2) {header('Location:menouTwo.php');} 
elseif ($_SESSION['role']==3) {header('Location:menouThree.php');}
```

menouOne for example, has only "update/delete/insert" and menouThree has also "add new user" in addition to menouOne.

This practice, sounds good to me , but I have to create so many different files.

So, my questions

1. Is this a good practice, or there is a much more easier/faster?
2. Do you have any links about creating new users in postgreSQL? I found some, but I'm still confused.
3. Do you have any links about adding md5 security to postgreSQL?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would send all users to the same page and `switch` between the different settings within that page.

For example

```
<?
$_SESSION['role']=$arr['role'];
header("location:themenu.php");
exit;
?>

<?
//themenu.php
session_start();
switch($_SESSION['role'])
{
    case 1://html for role 1
    {
        $controls['update'] = '<div id="contr_update">update</div>';
        $controls['delete'] = '<div id="contr_delete">delete</div>';
        $controls['insert'] = '<div id="contr_insert">insert</div>';
        break;
    }
    case 2://html for role 2
    {
        $controls['update'] = '<div id="contr_update">update</div>';
        $controls['delete'] = '<div id="contr_delete">delete</div>';
        $controls['insert'] = '<div id="contr_insert">insert</div>';
        $controls['adduser'] = '<div id="contr_adduser">add new user</div>';
        break;
    }
    case 3://html for role 3
    {
        $controls['update'] = '<div id="contr_update">update</div>';
        $controls['delete'] = '<div id="contr_delete">delete</div>';
        $controls['insert'] = '<div id="contr_insert">insert</div>';
        $controls['adduser'] = '<div id="contr_adduser">add new user</div>';
        $controls['other'] = '<div id="contr_other">other functions</div>';
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        header("location:login.php");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...some html
<? echo $controls['update']; ?>
...some more html
<? echo $controls['delete']; ?>
...some more html
<? echo $controls['insert']; ?>
...some more html
<? echo $controls['adduser']; ?>
...some more html
<? echo $controls['other']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

When storing a password in the database you should encrypt it with MD5 so you can then compare it to the supplied password when a user logs in.

$password = md5($password);
The save $password to the database.

When a user logs in you do the same as above and compare the two encrypted passwords for a match.